# React Bootstrap 4 Align Items in Header

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap v1.0.0-beta.5 which uses bootstrap 4.

I am trying to create a header that aligns text on one side and an ellipsis on the other that will drop down actions when you click it.

I have attemped to use

`<FaEllipsisH className="justify-content-end"/>`

What should I be doing?

```
   <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }} className="pCard" border="dark">
     <Card.Header>
       <FaAmazon/> {product.content}
       <FaEllipsisH className="justify-content-end"/>
     </Card.Header>
     <Card.Body>
       <Card.Title> <FaFileInvoice/> <span className="Home orderNo"><a href={`/products/${product.productId}`}>{product.productId}</a></span></Card.Title>
       <Card.Text>Item</Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
```

Associated CSS

```
.Home .pCard {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Looks like flex box, in which case your parent container will need to have the `display: flex` property.

Comment: I added that but it doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `justify-content: space-between` from flexbox. You can use Bootstrap's [flex utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content) classes:

```
<Card.Header className="d-flex justify-content-between">
```